# Looping through javascript nested object returning undefined

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I am trying to loop through a nested object, but I keep returning undefined.

My object:

```
var ltColumns = {

"col1": {data: "productCode", title: "Product Code", width: "7%" },

"col2": {data: "brand", title: "Brand", width: "5%"}
};
```

My loop:

```
for (var key in ltColumns) {
  console.log(key.data);
}
```

In this case, I am trying to console log the "data" attribute of each nested object. However, I keep getting 'undefined'. Can someone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your loop to:

```
for (var key in ltColumns) {
    console.log(ltColumns[key].data);
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/oz966jjz/)

Your `for...in` loop returns a property name on each iteration to `key`, here `col1` and `col2`. So the statement `key.data` by itself would return undefined because neither `col1` nor `col2` are an object -- they're properties of `ltColumns`. So you need to use `key` and `ltColumns` together to get the value of the `col1` and `col2` properties since `ltColumns` is the actual object.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
    console.log(ltColumns[key].data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var key in ltColumns) {
   console.log(key.data); // key is just a string, not the property itself
                          // "col1".data, "col2".data, etc. 
                          // and these strings do not have `data` property
}
```

You want to [access the properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4244912/1367611). Hence `object[property]` since the dot notation is not possible.